# How to handle null values when trying to search a listview in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am a beginner in xamarin forms. I am trying to sort a listview based on City, state, location name and zip code.

If one of these is empty , how can i search for the rest of the list ?

listView.ItemsSource = locs.Where(i => (i.City.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower())) || (i.State.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower())) || (i.LocationName.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower())) || (i.Zip.Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()))) || locs.Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the null conditional operator, `?`

```
locs.Where(i => (i.City?.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()))
```

note the `?` after `City` - if `City` is null then the rest of the statement will not execute

alternately, you could check for null explicitly

```
locs.Where(i => (iCity != null && i.City.ToLower().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLower()))
```

Comment: Jason, In the list view if there are 5 locations and if any one the location does not have a single property (City or State )the App crashes. So, if I handle the null values this way.. when the list view is being sorted, how will it handle that case ?

Comment: you might be better off being sure that City and State are always initialized to string.Empty